# How to filter layers using forEachFeatureAtPixel method

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm having hard time figuring out how to filter layers using **forEachFeatureAtPixel**  method. I was going trough documentation but without any success so far. I basically want to filter layers and apply overlay style on event (for example "click") or to be more precise I want to implement hover effect using this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html?q=geojson) but with isolated layer.

In example above is used like this to get feature:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
          return feature;
        });
```

I wanted to tweak code a bit by using layer filter but I got `syntax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` syntax error:

```
 var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(pixel, function(features) {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('layer_name') === 'someName';
        }
    });
```

Then, I tried like this

```
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('layer_name') === 'someName';
        }
    });
```

but then I got `Uncaught TypeError: d.call is not a function` error

I'm using documentation but to be fair I'm kind of struggling with reading and implementing some of the methods [API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.CanvasMap.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it. I was a bit hasty while reading documentation, problem was in callback function. I needed to return feature as it is pointed out in documentation. *...To stop detection, callback functions can return a truthy value.*

So, proper formatting is like this:  (I'm using 4.5.6 version)

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
        return feature;
    }, {
        layerFilter: function(layer) {
            return layer.get('layer_name') === 'someName';
        }
    });
```

Now is working properly. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

For those who suffered like me with layer names I can suggest you that below way as an alternative;

I have stored my all layers in variables then filter them like this;

```
var countryLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: countryLayerSource,
  style: //some styling in here
});

...

var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
  pixel,
  function (feature) {
    return feature;
  },
  {
    layerFilter: function (layer) {
      return layer === countryLayer;
    },
  }
);
```

Used API: v6.3.1. [Openlayers API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html)